# Subquery for split_string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables in SQL Server. One holds the names of fields, the other is a combination of the id's. I'm a bit newer to more advanced SQL queries and am having trouble figuring out a good way to accomplish this. If I were using javascript I would just split each data address into an array and loop over each to give me the desired output. Not sure how to accomplish in SQL.

```
t1
```

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Manager |
| 1 | Client |
| 2 | FirstName |
| 3 | LastName |

```
t2
```

| dataaddress |
| --- |
| 0.2 |
| 0.3 |
| 1.2 |
| 1.3 |

Desired Output:

| addressname |
| --- |
| Manager.FirstName |
| Manager.LastName |
| Client.FirstName |
| Client.LastName |

I've tried using split_string to parse out each from dataaddress but am having trouble figuring out / a good google search for a way to accomplish this.

Comment: Well you shouldn't store your data like that in the first place. Putting multiple values in the same column defeats the purpose of using a relational database.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Would the data address always be 2 number separated by a dot? 
I would create a SQL function which takes a number as a parameter and then returns the name from t1.  You could then split the values and call the function with each value.  I can provide more info if required?

Comment: @HHS, it usually is only 2 numbers separated by a dot, I forgot to mention that there are instances in the table where there are up to 5. There are also instances where there is only one number and no dot. Any additional info would be appreciated.

Comment: Store one value per field. Do not use delimtered strings in relational databases. Would you use a hammer to drive a screw?  If you have a 1:1..many relationship, the normal form has many rows, not many values in a single string.

Comment: It's a vendor's DB, I don't have any control of how the data is stored. Any helpful suggestions or recommendations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl1 TABLE (id INT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(20));
INSERT @tbl1 (id, name) VALUES
(0, 'Manager'),
(1, 'Client'),
(2, 'FirstName'),
(3, 'LastName');

DECLARE @tbl2 TABLE (dataaddress VARCHAR(20));
INSERT @tbl2 (dataaddress) VALUES
('0.2'),
('0.3'),
('1.2'),
('1.3');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT t1_id = PARSENAME(dataaddress,2)
        , t2_id = PARSENAME(dataaddress,1) 
    FROM @tbl2
)
SELECT addressname = CONCAT(t1.name, '.' , t2.name)
FROM @tbl1 AS t1 INNER JOIN rs ON t1.id = rs.t1_id
    INNER JOIN @tbl1 AS t2 ON t2.id = rs.t2_id;
```

**Output**

| addressname |
| --- |
| Manager.FirstName |
| Manager.LastName |
| Client.FirstName |
| Client.LastName |

Comment: Thanks! I have it working, but I did forget to mention that there could be just one or more than 2 numbers in dataaddress.

Comment: Glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. I hope you understand now importance of the **minimal reproducible example**: ##1-4